# How to efficiently pass initial value to get_variable

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I want to create a variable using `tf.get_variable` and it should be initialized with a numpy array.

As far as I know, there are two ways to create a variable, `tf.Variable` and `tf.get_variable`. We can easily pass initial values to variables created by `tf.Variable`. But there seems to be no direct ways to do the same thing towards those created by `tf.get_variable`.

What I have been doing now is to firstly create a tensor with numpy array by using `tf.convert_to_tensor` and then pass this tensor as the `initializer` to `tf.get_variable`. But this in no way seems efficient to me, since I have a really large array as initial value, then I have to store this large array twice in my graph.

Therefore, I wonder if there are some more efficient ways of doing that? Is using `Variable` the only way to avoid the efficiency problem that I mentioned above?

Comment: Have you tried using `tf.constant_initializer()`? ([doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#constant_initializer))
With it you can just pass the numpy array as argument with copying it to a Tensor.

Comment: Didn't know it, thanks. But that's weird, In the document of `tf.constant_initializer`, it says the argument "value: A Python scalar. All elements of the initialized variable will be set to this value". But it  really works when passing a numpy array instead of a scalar to it. Do you know the reason?

Comment: No I think it is typo in the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is to use the function `tf.constant_initializer(value)` of TensorFlow (cf.[doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers/Constant)).

Although the documentation says to use only scalar values, you can pass a numpy array of any dimension.